# Better way to extend SVG.Element that lets vscode know the change has been made and provides documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, svg.js

I'm working with [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/) and the [documentation](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/extending/) describes a way to extend the classes within the library in order to add extra functionality to all the objects that extend that class.

I've come up with this example to provide a red bounding box for any object that inherits from `SVG.Element`.

```
import * as SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';

SVG.extend(SVG.Element, {
    bounding_box: function(margin) {
        var bbox = this.bbox()
        return this.parent().rect({
            x: bbox.x - margin/2,
            y: bbox.y - margin/2,
            width: bbox.width + margin,
            height: bbox.height + margin
        })
        .stroke("red")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
    }
})
```

However, although this works, the fact that this happens at runtime does not allow vscode to provide intelligent recommendations for this functionality on the objects that inherit from `SVG.Element`. Just as well, I am unable to provide anyone using this functionality documentation *for this functionality*.

I've attempted to alter the `node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.node.js` file as well as the `node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/elements/Element.js` **in the body of the Element class** to include my functionality, but upon attempting to use it I get an error saying that the function does not exist.

I would prefer to contribute to the [open source project on github](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js), but until I can figure out these damn files and what is actually going to work I'm afraid I'll be of no use.

Which file do I need to alter in order to write in new functionality to the `SVG.Element` class of the library? Do I need to clone the repo and do a rebuild?

I've never done open source before so this will be a first for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliSense makes use of a subset of [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app) syntax to enhance code completion. Unfortunately, the documentation of what works or not is patchy. [This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript) makes a lot of promises, but [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) the list of what works is much smaller.

The proper JSDoc way to describe this sort of class extension would be with a `@mixin MyExtension` annotation for the object literal used as parameter for `SVG.extend()` and then annotate the class with a `@mixes MyExtension`. This does not work in VSCode v1.48.

Instead, while the use of the `@memberof` annotation is listed as "buggy", it seems to - kindof - work. The method you want to mixin must be written separately from the object literal:

```
//mockup for the purpose of testing
const SVG = {};

SVG.Element = class {
    bbox () {
        return {x:0, y:0, width:1, height:1}
    }
    parent () {
        return this;
    }
}

/** 
 * @memberof SVG.Element
 * @param {number} margin
 */
function bounding_box (margin) {
    var bbox = this.bbox()
    return this.parent().rect({
        x: bbox.x - margin/2,
        y: bbox.y - margin/2,
        width: bbox.width + margin,
        height: bbox.height + margin
    })
    .stroke("red")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
}

SVG.extend(SVG.Element, {bounding_box});
```

The `this` inside the `bounding_box` function is then correctly identified as being of type `SVG.Element`. When writing

```
const el = SVG.Element();
el.bounding_box()
```

`.bounding_box` is not listed as a method in the hints, but the `margin` parameter is correctly typed.

[image]

In the sidebar, the outline shows `.bounding_box` as a member of `SVG.Element`, but as a property, not a method.

[image]